# How to set default value in DropDownListFor in a loop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dropdown

I just want to show a drop down list on my view with a selected value/state, but the problem is that selected state/value doesn't work. After some researching on this website I couldn't find my solution and write this post, It seems it's simple but I'm confused. Maybe my case is a little complicated.

In my cause my drop down gets items(MarriageList) froma listand selected values from another list(PersonList).

Main model on my view, I create an instant and pass it to view by controller:

```
  Public class MyPageModel
  {
    //this is my marriage list and to use anywhere on my codes
    Public List<Sub_MarriageModel> MarriageList { get; set; }

    //this is person list selected marriage is in this list
    Public List<Person> PersonList{get;set;}
}
```

This is my items class:

```
public class Sub_MarriageModel
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }  // 0,1,2
    public string Name { get; set; } //single,married
}

public class Person
{
    public int SelectesState{ get; set; }  // 0,1,2
}
```

View is:

```
@for (int i=0;i<Model.MarriageList.Count;i++)
{ 
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.PersonList[i].SelectesState,
                      new SelectList(Model.MarriagesList, "ID", "Name"))
}
```

HTML result:

```
<select id="PersonList_0__SelectesState" name="PersonList[0].SelectesState">
 <option value="0">Single</option>
 <option value="1">Married</option>
 <option value="2">Unknow</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you MarriageList do you need multiple dropdowns

```html
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.PersonList[i].SelectesState,new SelectList(Model.MarriagesList, "ID", "Name"), "Unknow")
```